# How to divide values by day in [R]

Tags: r, date, syntax, days

I have a data like this.

```
spot3new<- aggregate(spot3$Price~spot3$Date, spot3, sum)


head(spot3new)
spot3$Date    spot3$Price
1 2011-01-01      -16.32
2 2011-01-02      861.11
3 2011-01-03     1381.69
4 2011-01-04     1497.08
5 2011-01-05     1228.44
6 2011-01-06     1226.26
```

Here,I sum up hourly prices by date. So 24 hours' prices are summed up together. Now I want to divide them by the number of hours to make average price out of it. 
So I did this.

```
spot3newD<- data.frame(spot3new$`spot3$Date`, spot3new$`spot3$Price`/24)

> head(spot3newD)
     spot3new..spot3.Date.    spot3new..spot3.Price..24
1            2011-01-01                  -0.68000
2            2011-01-02                  35.87958
3            2011-01-03                  57.57042
4            2011-01-04                  62.37833
5            2011-01-05                  51.18500
6            2011-01-06                  51.09417
```

But I realized, out of 48000 observations, there are a few missing values. So if I divide by 24, it will not yield 'daily average price' because from somewhere middle of my data, price will be pulled or pushed due to missing values. 
So I do not want to divide my data `by 24`. I want to divide `by date or days` for everyday from 2015-12-31 to 2011-01-02 So that they will not be any miscalculation.

Can anyone help me with syntax?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want calculate daily mean, you can use aggregate function, as long as you have date in Date format.

```
dailymean <- aggregate(Price ~ day(Date), data, mean, na.rm=T)
```

'day' function from 'lubridate' package

Comment: Hello. I tried what you said, but it only shows 31 days as day function only counts days not months and years. I need every single day from 2015-12-31 to 2011-01-02. Could you guide me a bit? Thanks.

Comment: Really, you are right. The solution is consider only Date without day function. `dailymean <- aggregate(Price ~ Date, data, mean, na.rm=T)`. Please let me know if this works well. If not try with: "as.factor(Date)" or "day(Date) + month(Date) + year(Date)"

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I have done it.